# Calculate Split Balances based on range in SQL

Tags: t-sql

Need some help on splitting the daily balance based on the **Min** and **Max** range.

I have a table with an account with a balance 19447.83 in a **balance table** on one particular day.

I have a **range table** where for every product where the balance is split as follows

```
Range Table             
Product_Code    Product_Description Min_Range   Max_Range   Interest_Rate
2000-0100   Saving  0   4999.99 0.01
2000-0100   Saving  5000    9999.99 0.02
2000-0100   Saving  10000   49999.99    0.03
2000-1111   Senior Savings  0   4999.99 0.03
2000-1111   Senior Savings  5000    9999.99 0.04
2000-1111   Senior Savings  10000   49999.99    0.05
```

```
Balance Table               
Date            Balance    Product_Code     Product_Description AccountNo
28/02/2019  19447.83    2000-0100   Saving          3059123
27/02/2019  19557.61    2000-0100   Saving          3059123
26/02/2019  19976.01    2000-0100   Saving          3059123
25/02/2019  20530.91    2000-0100   Saving          3059123
28/02/2019  12345           2000-1111   Senior Savings  4059123
27/02/2019  5456            2000-1111   Senior Savings  4059123
26/02/2019  9999            2000-1111   Senior Savings  4059123
25/02/2019  7893            2000-1111   Senior Savings  4059123
```

The balance on 28/02/2019  19447.83 Should be split into

```
0 to 4999.99         0.01
5000 to 9999.99      0.02
10000 to 19447.83    0.03
```

Comment: What kind of help do you need?

Comment: Looking for help in  SQL to derive this

Comment: Why is this marked as too broad?  This is a very straightforward problem...

Comment: @IamDave: Thanks a lot mate. The solution solved my purpose. :)

Comment: @iamdave re "Too Broad" see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384183/should-we-encourage-sql-questions-that-just-dump-a-schema-without-any-attempt-fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly basic joining and arithmetic:

```
declare @r table(Product_Code varchar(20),Product_Description varchar(20),Min_Range decimal(10,2),Max_Range decimal(10,2),Interest_Rate decimal(10,2));
insert into @r values('2000-0100','Saving',0,4999.99,0.01),('2000-0100','Saving',5000,9999.99,0.02),('2000-0100','Saving',10000,49999.99,0.03),('2000-1111','Senior Savings',0,4999.99,0.03),('2000-1111','Senior Savings',5000,9999.99,0.04),('2000-1111','Senior Savings',10000,49999.99,0.05);

declare @b table(BalanceDate date,Balance decimal(10,2),Product_Code varchar(20),Product_Description varchar(20),AccountNo int);
insert into @b values('20190228',19447.83,'2000-0100','Saving',3059123),('20190227',19557.61,'2000-0100','Saving',3059123),('20190226',19976.01,'2000-0100','Saving',3059123),('20190225',20530.91,'2000-0100','Saving',3059123),('20190228',12345,'2000-1111','Senior Savings',4059123),('20190227',5456,'2000-1111','Senior Savings',4059123),('20190226',9999,'2000-1111','Senior Savings',4059123),('20190225',7893,'2000-1111','Senior Savings',4059123);

select b.AccountNo
      ,b.Product_Code
      ,b.Product_Description
      ,b.BalanceDate
      ,b.Balance
      ,r.Min_Range
      ,r.Max_Range
      ,r.Interest_Rate
      ,case when b.Balance > r.Max_Range
            then r.Max_Range - r.Min_Range
            else b.Balance - r.Min_Range
            end as Split_Balance
      ,r.Interest_rate * case when b.Balance > r.Max_Range
                            then r.Max_Range - r.Min_Range
                            else b.Balance - r.Min_Range
                            end as Split_Balance_Interest
from @b as b
    join @r as r
        on b.Product_Code = r.Product_Code
            and b.Balance > r.Min_Range
order by b.AccountNo
        ,b.BalanceDate;
```